# Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int solved with CONVERT() ... but WHY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

My question is about WHY?  WHAT is SQL doing to cause this error message in the situation below.

There are a few of these queries on stack but usually because of a missing DateAdd().  Here I am simply trying to put the date passed in as part of an audit note string against the record.  I am not specifically asking the two variables to play together and give me a result.

Below is the line of issue.  At the bottom the fuller query for context.

@Days INT,
@Date DATE

**'Extension to claim of ' + @Days + ' from ' + @Date + '.' ,**

```
SELECT TOP 1
                ID,
                WorkFlowStatusCode ,
                'Number of days: ' + @Days + ' from ' + @Date + '.' ,
                @UserId ,
                @UserId
        FROM    dbo.Table
        WHERE   ID= @VariableA
        ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

What I have found is that wrapping the @Date in a Convert() to 103 solves the issue.  See Below.

**'Extension to claim of ' + @Days + ' from ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),@Date,103) + '.' ,**

I am simply trying to understand why I would need to do that in this situation from SQL/Database point of view.  I can't find that answer online to help my understanding.

All comments greatly appreciated.

Lee

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `@Day` is an integer.  Remember that `+` can mean both addition and string concatenation, so SQL can get confused.  Try this:

```
'Number of days: ' + convert(varchar(255), @Days) + ' from ' + convert(varchar(10), @Date, 103) + '.'
```

Notes:

- When using `varchar()` or `nvarchar()`, always include a length.  SQL Server has a default length that varies by context.  Not including the length is an easy way to create a very-hard-to-debug error.
- Your code suggests `varchar()` rather than `nvarchar()` because the rest of the string are not national character sets.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, the days I will be casting so I guess without the implicit conversions to work in a string SQL is considering these two values are trying to provide a result?

Comment: @user3083791 . . . Never depend on implicit conversions; always try to be explicit.  Some of my worst debugging nightmares were due to implicit conversions.